# Mobile web view displays active tab as white rectangle

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The mobile web view of several Stack Exchange sites displays the 
"active tab" as a white rectangle:

[image]

Observed with Safari on OS X and Mobile Safari on iOS,

- on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions,
- not on https://stackoverflow.com/questions.

Comment: Also observed in Chrome on desktop computer. The bug is in the CSS: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UbpJE.png /cc @Oded

Comment: And chromium/android stock browser.

Comment: I've got it on Android/Chrome http://i.stack.imgur.com/Eim6M.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've introduced slightly updated styling for current menu item. This was because of some changes in mobile web we're working on right now. Obviously invisible label was a bug but it is fixed now.

Thanks again for reporting.